# Mysql join gives duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables and i am using join to get common records from those 2 tables. i have used the following query but my problem is i am getting the records doubled. The query is as follows

```
SELECT * FROM pos_metrics pm INNER JOIN pos_product_selling pps ON   
pm.p_id=pps.p_id WHERE pm.p_id='0' AND pps.pos_buying_id='0' AND pm.type=1
```

pos_metrics table:
[image]

pos_product_selling table:
[image]

Output:

[image]

EDIT
When I tried to use GROUP BY and DISTINCT together I am not getting duplicates but the value from the second table is repeated. Any other solutions ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a primary key in the `pos_metrics` table and introduce it to the `pos_product_selling` table, then do a `JOIN` based on the primary key as well as the other criteria. You won't get these duplicates then.

The reason you have duplicates over here is because there is no possibility of an unique comparison to be done on both tables based on a value.

Comment: What do you mean by "and introduce it to the `pos_product_selling` table"

Comment: @Ricky B He means create a column on the pos_product_selling table whose value is a primary key on pos_metrics. A typical name for  such a column would be "pos_metrics_id"

Answer (score 22):

Try something like these

```
GROUP BY pos_product_selling.metrics
```

Comment: Can you comment your answer?

Comment: Answer was easy but not shown lol , thank you Jayak ;)

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ...
GROUP BY pm.metrics
```

Comment: this is working but is this the right way to do ?? i am dealing with thousands of record here..

Answer (score 5):

To eliminate dups, use distinct:

```
select distinct * from ...
```

But I've a feeling your question is about something else -- and that you'd need to post the specific code for more help.

Comment: My feeling is you need a group by/having somewhere, but your question is lacking context.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's the expected result. Shouldn't you be using something like: `select distinct pm.* from ...`?

Comment: INNER JOIN may create unique rows with only one different column, so distinct may not reduce result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM pos_metrics pm, pos_product_selling pps
Where pm.p_id=pps.p_id AND pm.p_id='0' AND pps.pos_buying_id='0' AND pm.type=1
```

try the above query

Answer (score 0):

After reading this subject I could not think there was something going on. I had the same issue and nailed it down to one table which was

```
CREATE TABLE `$dbname`.`$table` (
`prtcatid` INT NOT NULL,
`prtcat` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
);
```

The only difference between this table and all the others was there was no primary index.
the code was changed to

```
CREATE TABLE `$dbname`.`$table` (
`prtcatid` INT NOT NULL,
`prtcat` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`prtcatid`)
);
```

the doubling of the rows then ceased. This solution was prompted by the suggestion in an previous answer above.
Hope this may help others.