# MySQL Full Text Search Match Against Query AND OR Column1 = ABC

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

This works;

```
SELECT MATCH('Col1', 'Col2') AGAINST('search query') AS Score, Col1, Col2, Col3 
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
Col1 = 'something-1' 
OR 
Col2 = 'something-2' 
OR 
MATCH('Col1', 'Col2') AGAINST ('search query') HAVING Score > 2;
```

This doesn't;

```
SELECT MATCH('Col1', 'Col2') AGAINST('search query') AS Score, Col1, Col2, Col3 
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
Col1 = 'something-1' 
OR 
Col2 = 'something-2' 
OR 
MATCH('Col1', 'Col2') AGAINST ('search query') HAVING Score > 2 
AND Col3 = 'something3';
```

I'm not sure this is bringing back the exact results I want yet, although this is the main issue: How to use Match Against with an AND, and most importantly, chain things together effectively with (brackets) to prioritise the correct mixture of;

```
(X = 1 OR Y = 2 OR MATCH('Col1', 'Col2') AGAINST ('search query') HAVING Score > 2) AND Z = 3
```

From my tests for every combination so far, I've not managed to get this to work effectively. I'm trying to expand a current complex query which just uses AND and ORs currently to also include MATCH AGAINST information which is of a certain quality.

There must be a correct way of doing this that I'm not doing properly.

**Update 1**
Interestingly, when I implement the query suggested and use the AND statement first as below;

```
Col3 = 'something3' AND
(
    Col1 = 'something-1' 
    OR 
    Col2 = 'something-2' 
    OR 
    MATCH('Col1', 'Col2') AGAINST ('search query')  > 2 
);
```

Then this actually returns duplicate results.

Comment: How should the query be structured? When I change to the following query, the error Unknown column 'Score' in 'where clause', appears: SELECT MATCH('Col1', 'Col2') AGAINST('search query') AS Score, Col1, Col2, Col3 
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
(Col1 = 'something-1' 
OR 
Col2 = 'something-2' 
OR 
Score > 2 )
AND Col3 = 'something3';

Comment: I take it back, I did not read your statements properly. if your statement returns data multiple times its kind of strange. If you can explain a bit what you actualy want to acmoplish it would be helpfull, deleting first comment as its irelevant

Comment: Figured this bit out, the duplicates were being caused because the JOIN was using a unique field, not the Primary Key field, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352454/mysql-join-gives-duplicate-rows

Comment: well its hard to answer if you do not explain whole question :)

Comment: by the way NEVER ever mix OR and AND wihout brackets its extremly dangerous as you cant be sure how code is interpreted

Comment: Agreed, I'll update the question, should have added that into the code example to explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems that you simply need

```
(
    Col1 = 'something-1' 
    OR 
    Col2 = 'something-2' 
    OR 
    MATCH('Col1', 'Col2') AGAINST ('search query')  > 2 
)
AND Col3 = 'something3';
```

Comment: Thats what I would have thought, although that throws an error.... Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING Score > 1);

Comment: The query works when I remove the ( ) surrounding the various OR bits, and the query also works when I remove the "Having Score > 1" part. Although I need both of these in

Comment: you don't need the having clause since it is replaced by the condition already inside the OR.

Comment: @Arilla How would you filter the results that are over a certain score? This Score value is the calculated value that the MySQL Full Text Search is doing, this section is to remove low quality results from the search results

Comment: so put that condition out of the OR parentesis. You provided an example and my code should fulfill that example. If you want to filter all the rows then you can do `(
    Col1 = 'something-1' 
    OR 
    Col2 = 'something-2' 
      
) AND MATCH('Col1', 'Col2') AGAINST ('search query')  > 2 
AND Col3 = 'something3';`

Comment: The MATCH AGAINST part needs to be part of the OR, not as an AND in the last example above. I've not managed to get this to work when keeping the Col1 OR Col2 OR MATCH AGAINST all within the parenthesis, and adding in an AND afterwards.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I'm being an idiot. I'll post an answer in a minute for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided by @Arilia works perfectly. Tip to myself mainly (and others if you've stumbled upon this with a similar problem) When building complex queries, always remember that when calculating the Score that is generated by MySQL Full Text Searches, this will not apply to every row in the results set, some will show 0 as they won't have been triggered by this part of the query, they will have been triggered by other simpler parts of the query. Schoolboy error.

```
SELECT MATCH('Col1', 'Col2') AGAINST('search query') AS Score, Col1, Col2, Col3 
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
(
    Col1 = 'something-1' 
    OR 
    Col2 = 'something-2' 
    OR 
    MATCH('Col1', 'Col2') AGAINST ('search query')  > 2 
)
AND
Col3 = 'something3';
```